# How to write a set of fields to JSON?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write few fields in my data frame to JSON. My data structure in the data frame is

```
Key|col1|col2|col3|col4
key|a   |b   |c   |d
Key|a1  |b1  |c1  |d1
```

Now i am trying to convert just the col1 to col4 fields to JSON and give a name to the Json field

expected output

```
[Key,{cols:[{col1:a,col2:b,col3:c,col4:d},{col1:a1,col2:b1,col3:c1,col4:d1}]
```

I wrote a udf for this.

```
val summary = udf( 
(col1:String, col2:String, col3:String, col4:String) => "{\"cols\":[" + "  {\"col1\":" + col1 + ",\"col2\":" + col2 + ",\"col3\":" + col3 + ",\"col4\":" + col4 + "}]}"
)

val result = input.withColumn("Summary",summary('col1,'col2,'col3,'col4))
val result1 = result.select('Key,'Summary)
result1.show(10)
```

This is my result

```
[Key,{cols:[{col1:a,col2:b,col3:c,col4:d}]}]
[Key,{cols:[{col1:a1,col2:b1,col3:c1,col4:d1}]}]
```

As you can see, they are not grouped. Is there a way to group these rows using the UDF itself. I am new to scala/Spark and not able to figure out the proper udf.

Comment: I don't think you've terminated your 'expected output' correctly; I would expect there to be another "}]" at the end to match the opening "[{".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDFs will map one row to one row. If you have multiple rows in your `DataFrame` that you want to combine into one element, you're going to need to use a function like `reduceByKey` that aggregates multiple rows.

There may be a `DataFrame` specific function to do this, but I would do this processing with the `RDD` functionality, like so:

```
val colSummary = udf( 
(col1:String, col2:String, col3:String, col4:String) => "{\"col1\":" + col1 + ",\"col2\":" + col2 + ",\"col3\":" + col3 + ",\"col4\":" + col4 + "}"
)
val colRDD = input.withColumn("Summary",summary('col1,'col2,'col3,'col4)).rdd.map(x => (x.getString(0),x.getString(5)))
```

This gives us a `RDD[(String,String)]`, which will allow us to use the `PairRDDFunctions` like `reduceByKey` (see the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions)). The key of the tuple is the original key, and the value is the json encoding for a single element that we need to aggregate together to make the `cols` list. We glue them all together into a comma-separated list, and then we add the beginning and end, and then we're done.

```
val result = colRDD.reduceByKey((x,y) => (x+","+y)).map(x => "["+x._1+",{\"cols\":["+x._2+"]}]")
result.take(10)
```

Comment: Thank you.it worked. Just making few edits(explained in this comment) in the answer. val colRDD is missing a ')' at the end. and also result is missing a ')' at the end. In colRDD, it is x.getString(5) instead of x.getString(1) as Summary will be the 5th field after we add a field to the input data frame. And finally result.take(10) as 'result' is an rdd.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Create your dataset
scala> val ds = Seq((1, "hello", 1L), (2, "world", 2L)).toDF("id", "token", "long")
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, token: string ... 1 more field]

// select the fields you want to map to json
scala> ds.select('token, 'long).write.json("your-json")

// check the result
➜  spark git:(master) ✗ ls -ltr your-json/
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 jacek  staff  27 11 kwi 17:18 part-r-00007-91f81f62-54bb-42ae-bddc-33829a0e3c16.json
-rw-r--r--  1 jacek  staff   0 11 kwi 17:18 part-r-00006-91f81f62-54bb-42ae-bddc-33829a0e3c16.json
-rw-r--r--  1 jacek  staff   0 11 kwi 17:18 part-r-00005-91f81f62-54bb-42ae-bddc-33829a0e3c16.json
-rw-r--r--  1 jacek  staff   0 11 kwi 17:18 part-r-00004-91f81f62-54bb-42ae-bddc-33829a0e3c16.json
-rw-r--r--  1 jacek  staff  27 11 kwi 17:18 part-r-00003-91f81f62-54bb-42ae-bddc-33829a0e3c16.json
-rw-r--r--  1 jacek  staff   0 11 kwi 17:18 part-r-00002-91f81f62-54bb-42ae-bddc-33829a0e3c16.json
-rw-r--r--  1 jacek  staff   0 11 kwi 17:18 part-r-00001-91f81f62-54bb-42ae-bddc-33829a0e3c16.json
-rw-r--r--  1 jacek  staff   0 11 kwi 17:18 part-r-00000-91f81f62-54bb-42ae-bddc-33829a0e3c16.json
-rw-r--r--  1 jacek  staff   0 11 kwi 17:18 _SUCCESS
➜  spark git:(master) ✗ cat your-json/part-r-00003-91f81f62-54bb-42ae-bddc-33829a0e3c16.json
{"token":"hello","long":1}
➜  spark git:(master) ✗ cat your-json/part-r-00007-91f81f62-54bb-42ae-bddc-33829a0e3c16.json
{"token":"world","long":2}
```